# age calculator with javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I was trying to create an age calculator with javascript.There is a condition if the birthday input fileds are empty then it will give an error massage.but now even the filed are empty and click on the submite button it's submiting and giving an auot days month and year.How can I solve this issue.Here is my java script code

```
let presentdate = document.getElementById("pdate");
let presentmonth = document.getElementById("pmonth");
let presentyear = document.getElementById("pyear");

var date = new Date();
var pdate = date.getUTCDate(); //present date
var pmonth = 1 + date.getUTCMonth(); //present month
var pYear = date.getUTCFullYear(); // present year
var month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
// present date , month and year
presentdate.value = pdate;
presentmonth.value = pmonth;
presentyear.value = pYear;
// set conditions
function isNum(arg) {
  var args = arg;
  if (args == "" || args == null || args.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  // argument to set only number in input
  args = args.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (
      (args.substring(i, i + 1) < "0" || args.substring(i, i + 1) > "9") &&
      args.substring(i, i + 1) != "."
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
// check date.it will set the date between 1-31.
function checkday(aa) {
  var val = aa.value;
  var valc = val.substring(0, 1);
  if (val.length > 0 && val.length < 3) {
    if (!isNum(val) || val == 0) {
      aa.value = "";
    } else if (val < 1 || val > 31) {
      aa.value = valc;
    }
  } else if (val.length > 2) {
    val = val.substring(0, 2);
    aa.value = val;
  }
}
//check month.it will set month between 1-12.
function checkmonth(aa) {
  var val = aa.value;
  var valc = val.substring(0, 1);
  if (val.length > 0 && val.length < 3) {
    if (!isNum(val) || val == 0) {
      aa.value = "";
    } else if (val < 1 || val > 12) {
      aa.value = valc;
    }
  } else if (val.length > 2) {
    val = val.substring(0, 2);
    aa.value = val;
  }
}

function age() {
  let bdate = +document.getElementById("date").value;
  let bmonth = +document.getElementById("month").value - 1;
  let byear = +document.getElementById("year").value;

  if (bdate === "" || bmonth === "" || byear === "") {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Put Your Birthday";
    return;
  }else{
    let current = new Date();
    let birth = new Date(byear, bmonth, bdate);
    let difference = current - birth;

    let years = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
    difference -= years * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);

    let months = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30.4375));
    difference -= months * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30.4375);

    let days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    document.querySelector(".calc_result").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(
      "total_age"
    ).innerHTML = `${years} Years ${months} Months ${days} Days`;
    calculateDaysLived();
    calculateNextBirthday();
    // remove error text
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
  } 
  }

// total days
function calculateDaysLived() {
  let today = new Date();
  let birthdate = new Date(
    document.getElementById("year").value,
    document.getElementById("month").value - 1,
    document.getElementById("date").value
  );
  let timeDifference = today - birthdate;
  let daysLived = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  document.getElementById("total_day").innerHTML =
    "You lived " + daysLived + " days Since Your Birthday";
}
// next birtday
function calculateNextBirthday() {
  let today = new Date();
  let birthdate = new Date(
    document.getElementById("year").value,
    document.getElementById("month").value - 1,
    document.getElementById("date").value
  );
  birthdate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear());
  while (birthdate < today) {
    birthdate.setFullYear(birthdate.getFullYear() + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("next_bday").innerHTML =
    "Your next birthday is on " + birthdate.toDateString();
}
```

Comment: In your `function age() {...}`, instead of `let bdate = +document.getElementById("date").value;`, declare it like this `let bdate = document.getElementById("date").value;` (no plus sign, and no casting to a number). The same thing goes for the other inputs - pick them up as they are, check if they are empty strings, and if they're not, convert them to numbers in the `else` branch of your checkup. That's pretty much what @RoboRok was saying in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting date inputs to numbers and you're comparing them to an empty string. It's going to always be `false`:

```js
if (bdate === "" || bmonth === "" || byear === "") {
```

You can either check this condition before converting to numbers, or change the value you compare to.

Comment: How can I do that.could you help me with the code?